# Cópia de dados de tabela de forma sequencial com VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, automatização

Bom dia!

Preciso mesmo de ajuda. Tenho feito um indicador para atas de reunião. Ao longo dessas reuniões o trabalhador escreve a ata na tabela excel inclusivé problemas ou oportunidades de melhoria  que são faladas ao longo da reunião.

Esses problemas ou oportunidades de melhoria devem ser escritos em colunas separadas para que cada um dê inicio a um plano de ação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Numa folha chamada "Planos de Ações" fiz uma tabela e quero que por ordem apareçam os problemas. Por exemplo :

='Indicador de Atas'!O4
='Indicador de Atas'!P4
='Indicador de Atas'!Q4
='Indicador de Atas'!O5
='Indicador de Atas'!P5
='Indicador de Atas'!Q5
='Indicador de Atas'!O6
='Indicador de Atas'!P6
='Indicador de Atas'!Q6

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E por aí adiante. Se poder ser feito isto automáticamente e atualizado sempre que for escrita mais uma ata já é um bom avanço (eu filtro para não aparecerem os zeros). No entanto, se por acaso for possível escrever apenas os problemas sem aparecer as casas vazias era ainda melhor!

Muito obrigada se alguém me puder ajudar!
Ana Ferreira.

Answer (score 0):

Tudo bem?

Eu não sei qual é a estrutura inteira da sua planilha, então me concentrei no problema que você apontou, ou seja, de consolidar informações distribuídas por várias colunas em uma única coluna na aba ao lado.

A lógica do código abaixo é encontrar a última coluna preenchida na aba "Indicador de Atas" e, para cada coluna preenchida, as células com valor diferente de "vazio" são copiadas e coladas em ordem na coluna "D" da aba "Plano de Ações".

E isso até a última linha preenchida de cada coluna da aba "Indicador de Atas".

Eu tentei replicar a estrutura da planilha que você mostrou na pergunta para facilitar para você e coloquei esse código em um botão.

[image: Indicador de Atas]

[image: Plano]

Segue o código:

```
Private Sub btOrganiza_Click()

Dim W       As Worksheet
Dim WPlano  As Worksheet
Dim Ln      As Integer
Dim Col     As Integer
Dim UltCol  As Range
Dim UltCel  As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Atribui as abas da planilha às variáveis
Set W = Sheets("Indicador de Atas")
Set WPlano = Sheets("Plano de Ações")

'Limpa a coluna D da planilha Plano de Ações
WPlano.Select
WPlano.Range("D4:D1048576").ClearContents

'Encontra a última coluna existente na planilha Indicador de Atas
W.Select
Set UltCol = W.Range("XFD3").End(xlToLeft)

'Seleciona o primeiro intervalo em que estão os comentários
Ln = 4
Col = 15
W.Range(W.Cells(Ln, Col), W.Cells(Ln, Col)).Select

'Realiza a repetição até a última coluna preenchida
Do While Col <= UltCol.Column

    'Encontra a última linha preenchida na coluna atual
    Set UltCel = W.Range(Cells(1048576, Col), Cells(1048576, Col)).End(xlUp)
    
    Do While Ln <= UltCel.Row
        
        If W.Range(W.Cells(Ln, Col), W.Cells(Ln, Col)) <> "" Then
            
            W.Select
            W.Range(W.Cells(Ln, Col), W.Cells(Ln, Col)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            WPlano.Select
            WPlano.Range("D1048576").Select
            Selection.End(xlUp).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        
        
        End If
    
        Ln = Ln + 1
    
    Loop

    
    Col = Col + 1

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Esvazia as variáveis da memória
Set W = Nothing
Set WPlano = Nothing
Set UltCol = Nothing
Set UltCel = Nothing
Ln = 0
Col = 0

MsgBox "Pronto", vbOKOnly, "Status"

End Sub
```

Qualquer ponto, me avise.